# Display Event Date, Name and then List Names who have signed up?! MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Really need help! I know this is easy to do but can't get my mind to switch on. I have a db table called 'Bookings' inside of which is the table columns 'StartDate' 'EventTitle' 'Fornames' 'Surname'

What I want to do is query the db and echo a list of the events by their startdate and title and then next to each one display the names that have booked onto each event.

When i run the following code it shows the StartDate, EventTitle and Forename but repeats this for every entry - I hope this makes sense.

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM Bookings";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $row['StartDate'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $row['EventTitle'] . '</td>'
.'<td>' . $row['Forenames'] . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$sql = "SELECT StartDate, EventTitle, GROUP_CONCAT(Fornames) as Attendees
FROM Bookings
GROUP BY StartDate, EventTitle";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

echo '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['StartDate'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $row['EventTitle'] . '</td>'.'<td>' . $row['Attendees'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

A couple of notes:

- `mysql_fetch_array()` won't give you the field names in `$row`, but `mysql_fetch_assoc()` will.
- The code you posted would skip the first row of results
- `<table>` doesn't need to be put in for every row.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately still no joy. Still displaying multiple entries. what im trying to achieve is, 
11.09.2015  House Party  Jim, Bob, Dave, Pete 

13.10.2015  Pool Party  Frank, Mike, John 

etc etc … 

:/

Comment: Updated the query - try that.

Comment: Very near! everything perfect only names not displaying but instead are just displaying as 'Forenames' x the amount of names entered in table. ?!

Comment: Oh, whoops. I'm a bit tired. Take the `'` out of `GROUP_CONCAT('Fornames')` so it's `GROUP_CONCAT(Fornames)` - I've updated the query

Comment: group_concat is length limited. if your guests end having more than 1024 chars (default) total length, you WILL be truncating the names silently.

Comment: Unless you have access to some of the system variables: [group_concat_max_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len), which can be set on a per session basis.

Comment: @samlev this is now working brilliantly thank you, any ideas how I could now export this data to an .ics file or something similar to enable client to be able to see data in their Google calendar?